# How to make a widget blink in Qt with a delay of one second?

Tags: c++, qt, widget, delay, blink

I want to show and hide a widget with an interval of one second.
My code is like:

```
if(ui->widget->isVisible())
        ui->widget->hide();
else
        ui->widget->show();
```

I need a one-second gap between showing and hiding my widget. I also want this to be repeated so that the widget starts blinking.

Comment: For periodic tasks you should take a look at [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html) it should be posible:

```cpp
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
constexpr int i = 1000; // 1s
timer->setInterval(i);

connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this]{
    if (isVisible())
        hide();
    else
        show();
});

timer->start();
```